# Set event_scheduler in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to set the event to on for the bus table but it does not work. The table as well as the event is being created but the event is not being triggered. I have already set this line `event_scheduler = ON;` in mysql- my.ini and restart the server.

```
    // Create bus table
    stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bus"
            + "(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
            + "route int(11) NOT NULL,"
            + "latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
            + "longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
            + "created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

    stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  AutoDelete "
            + "ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE "
            + "DO "
            + "DELETE FROM bus WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)");
    stt.execute("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON");
```

Comment: Your event is non-repeating. It only executes once, 3 minutes from when you create it. Are you sure the event scheduler is enabled before you create the event?

Comment: And how to make the execution to repeat every 3 min? and how to enable the event sheduler? I thought every thing happen by creating the event and after enabling it in the my.cnf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html):

> To repeat actions at a regular interval, use an `EVERY` clause. [...] For example, `EVERY 6 WEEK` means “every six weeks”.

In your case, if you want to repeat this action every three minutes, your event should be created as follows:

```sql
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  AutoDelete 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE
-- OPTIONAL: STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
-- OPTIONAL: ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
DO 
    DELETE FROM bus WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
```

To check if the event scheduler is running, you can use one of the following options:

**1. `SHOW PROCESSLIST`**

```
show processlist;
+-----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------------------+------------------+
| Id  | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                  | Info             |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------------------+------------------+
| 243 | root            | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL                   | show processlist |
| 244 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL | Daemon  |    6 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL             |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------------------+------------------+
```

Notice that the event scheduler is a "DAEMON" process

**2. `SHOW VARIABLES`**

```
show global variables like 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
```